# Python, string is outputting "none"?

Tags: python, string, while-loop, ascii

I'm looping through a string and adding 1 to the ASCII value, but at the end, this "none" pops out. What is it?

```
str_numbers = input ('> ')

i=0

while i <len(str_numbers):
    x = print(chr(ord(str_numbers[i]) + 1), end="")
    i=i+1
    
print (x)
```

Sample output:

> abcdef
>
> bcdefgNone

Comment: Why did my question get downvoted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print()` does not return anything. Because it doesn't, it default to return `None`. This is why when you print x, None appears.

However, it still prints the item at `x = print(chr(ord(str_numbers[i]) + 1), end="")`

Get rid of the assignment (i.e the `x =` and later the `print(x)`)